# Instrumental variable in logistics regression in R (ivreg in AER)

Tags: r, logistic-regression

Does ivreg in AER support a logit regression with instrumental variables?

For example:

```
IV = ivreg (Mort ~ Age + Sex + APACHE + PART_SendImmed + ICU_AdmImmed + ICU_LOS | Age + Sex + APACHE + PART_SendImmed + NurseOCC_Adm + NurseOCC_Disch,
    data = test)
```

Where, `Mort` is a binary variable
`ICU_AdmImmed` and `ICU_LOS` are endogenous variables, and
`NurseOCC_Adm` and `NurseOCC_Disch` are two instrumental variables.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use a probit rather than a logit, which will both improve the interpretability as well as allow you to use `ivprob`.

```
data("mtcars")

library(ivprobit)

ivprob(I(mtcars$vs==0), mtcars$cyl, I(mtcars$disp>150), mtcars$hp)
```

> ```
> $coefficients
>           [,1]
> [1,] -62.48480
> [2,]  17.09827
> [3,] -74.66346
>
> $se
> [1]  93844628  28724155 134217728
>
> $tval
>               [,1]
> [1,] -6.658325e-07
> [2,]  5.952576e-07
> [3,] -5.562862e-07
>
> $pval
> numeric(0)
>
> $df
> numeric(0)
>
> $names
> [1] "(Intercept)" "X1"          "yhat"
> ```

I don't know of a canned package to do it in R using a logit, in fact I'm fairly sure there isn't one as this was the conclusion of an econjobrumors.com thread on the topic, however if there's some reason you'd prefer a logit to a probit, then you could always carry out the process [manually](http://repository.upenn.edu/edissertations/255/).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was trying to arrange all my variables in ivprobit but there are some errors. I have done as follows:                   iv2 = ivprobit (Mort_code ~ Age + Sex + APACHE + PART_SendImmed, ICU_AdmImmed+ ICU_LOS, NurseOCC_Adm + NurseOCC_Disch,
             data = ds_test)

Comment: @Ali I don't think you use `data =` or `~` in that package. You comma separate the terms, like in my example. It's like this: `ivprob(y, x1, y2, x)`. The documentation goes into more detail. You can display documentation like this `?ivprob`. Oh and to do multiple variables it's like this `x=mtcars$hp + mtcars$qsec`. If this answer was useful please consider marking it as the solution.

Comment: The regular `ivreg` uses two-stage least squares. In this case, what are the two stages of `ivprob`? Is it still OLS for the first stage?

Comment: @useR Yes that's correct. If you type the name of the command without the `()` you'll see the whole procedure. It uses `lm` in the first stage.

Comment: Thanks again. I have read the manual but was not really helpful. I followed what you have mentioned as below: iv2 <- ivprobit (Mort_code, ds_tes$Age + ds_tes$Sex + ds_test$APACHE + ds_test$PART_SendImmed, ds_test$ICU_AdmImmed + ds_test$ICU_LOS, ds_test$NurseOCC_Adm + ds_test$NurseOCC_Disch)                                                                   but I got following error: Error in UseMethod("ivprobit") : 
no applicable method for 'ivprobit' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"

Comment: @Ali Sure. It's hard to tell without the data but you may need to change the class double to numeric.

Comment: @Hack-R thanks for the answer. In my data I do not have any double type. They are Factor, num and int.